# Optimizar una funcion para reiniciar APP en Python

Tags: python-3.x, funciones, while

Soy nueva en el mundo de la programación con *Python*, y tengo la siguiente pregunta.

¿Como puedo mejorar la función mostrada a continuacion?

No quiero usar el ciclo *while*, puesto que el programa se podría quedar atascado y no ejecutar `self.vca.post('reset')`

```
def reset_vca_core(self):
        success = False
        print('Resetting VCAcore')
        while success is False:
            try:
                self.vca.post('reset')
            except Exception as e:
                print('PROBLEM STOPPING AND STARTING VCAserver: {}'.format(e))
                success = False
            else:

        print('VCAcore Reset')
        return success
```

Answer (score 0):

En ninguna parte cambias la variable `success`. Esta nunca será `True`, el `while` nunca terminara. No es que el `while` se quede atascado.

Después de ejecutar `self.vca.post()` con éxito (sin generar excepciones), puedes poner el indicar a `True`, así:

```
self.vca.post('reset')
success = True
```

Con eso, la condición del `while` ya no se cumplirá y terminara el ciclo.